# JUnit Call a test method in one class from another class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Had a quick look at past questions, couldn't see something similar so here goes:

I also made a mistake in choosing dummy names for this example to illustrate my point, I'll rename them.

I have a class which has a JUnit test:

```
public class CheckFilter {
    @Test
    public void Run_filter_test() {
        //some code
    } 
}
```

And then another class:

```
public class CheckVideoPlays {
    @Test
    public void Play_video_in_full() {
        //some more code here etc
    } 
}
```

Finally, how do I call these two tests from another class, obviously you can't extend multiple classes.

```
public class RunAllTests { 
    //How do i call both
    //eg
    //
    //Run_filter_test();
    //Play_video_in_full();
}
```

**Note: I don't want to call the class. Don't want to run as:**

> @RunWith(Suite.class)
>
> @Suite.SuiteClasses({
>
> CheckFilter.class,
>
> CheckVideoPlays.class
>
> })

Comment: You could put both test methods into `BaseTests` and let `CheckFilter` and `ConvertAll` extend `BaseTests`. JUnit also runs the test methods in super classes.

Comment: I don't want to put the test methods in BaseTests. They should stay in their respective class. One way is to duplicate it and put them all in BaseTests aswell, however I was trying to figure out if I can get away with it without duplicating it in 2 places.

Answer (score 1):

A few things.

1. Change the name of `Sanatize_all_inputs` to the (java standard form) camel case, perhaps `sanitizeAllImports`.  When using Java, obey Java.
2. It seems likely that you will sanitize inputs once per test,
   which, to me, indicates that you want a class level variable of type `ConvertAll` in your jUnit test class.
3. Either use composition (another class level variable of type `BaseTestBlammy`) or inheritance (extend class `BaseTestBlammy`) to acquire access to the `BaseTestBlammy` methods.

Here is an example:

```
public MyJunitTestKapow
extends BaseTestBlammy
{
    private final ConvertAll convertAll;

    public MyJunitTestKapow()
    {
        convertAll = new ConvertAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest()
    {
        convertAll.sanitizeAllInputs(...);

        ... // do the rest of the test here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You misunderstood the naming. I don't want to call sanitise to do 'sanitisation' - it was a dummy name for a method

Answer (score 0):

You could make static method in `ConvertAll.sanitize` then call this method in both `ConvertAll.Sanitise_all_inputs` test and `CheckFilter.Run_filter_test`

As better (more maintainable and powerful) solution you may create `Sanitiser` class with `sanitise()` method (method may be static or not). Then each class that requires sanitise functionality will call `Sanitiser.sanitise`. This soltion may be better in long run- you may pass paramethers to sanitise method (or to Sanitiser constructor), Sanitiser may have some internal state, etc

Side note: you may consider migrating to Junit5 (basically it is just change of imported packages). Junit5 has @DisplayName annotation that declares nice test method names (with spaces). So your test methods will respect Java naming convention.

```
@Test
@DiplayName("Sanitize all inputs")
public void sanitiseAllInputs() {
    //some more code here etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You misunderstood the naming. I don't want to call sanitise to do 'sanitisation' - it was a dummy name for a method